# How to control alignment when scaling in Jetpack Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

I have a Composable like this：

```
@Composable
@Preview
fun ScaleTest() {

    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .aspectRatio(1f),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.Center
    ) {
        Box(Modifier.size(200.dp).background(Color.Red))
        Box(Modifier.scale(0.8f).size(200.dp).background(Color.Green))
    }

}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emH08.png)

It is indeed shrunk, but the layout is still in accordance with the original size.
This is not what I want. I want the layout to be done according to its shrunk appearance, or I can control its alignment.

I hope the green box can be matched with the red Align the top of the box, which looks like the picture below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nz4Ba.png)

I guess some people will say that you can use the fillMaxSize(0.8f) , but this is not what I want, because I not only want the box to be scaled, but also the content inside the box.

How should I achieve this requirement? Thanks everyone for your thoughts.

Comment: You just want the Green box to be aligned on the Top Center of the red box correct?

Comment: Yes, I want to achieve something like this

Answer (score 0):

You can just change the `contentAlignment` property of the parent `Box` to `Alignment.TopCenter` as shown in the code.

```
Box(
    //...
    contentAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter
) {
    //...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the following code should work for your specific use-case with the given dimensions.

```
@Composable
@Preview
fun ScaleTest() {
    Box(
        Modifier
            .fillMaxWidth()
            .aspectRatio(1f),
        contentAlignment = Alignment.TopCenter // To align top center
    ) {
        Box(
            Modifier
                .size(200.dp)
                .background(Color.Red))
        Box(
            Modifier
                .offset(y = (-20).dp) // set offset to move it top 
                                      // 20dp because size is 200
                .scale(0.8f)
                .size(200.dp)
                .background(Color.Green))
    }
}
```

[Preview for above Composable](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1i1Vs.png)